# meteor ionic form is not submitting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, ionic-framework

```
<ion-view view-title="New Task">
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <form>
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Task Title" ng-model="newTask.title">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <textarea placeholder="Task Details" ng-model="newTask.details"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="button button-full button-balanced" ng-click="addTask()">
            Add Task
        </button>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is my view for the form. The form is to be submitted when the button is clicked

```
angular.module("Mine").controller("taskController",
    function ($scope, $meteor) {

        $scope.taskCol = $meteor.collections(Tasks);

        $scope.newTask = {};

           $scope.addTask = function ()
           {
               $scope.newTask.createdOn = new Date();
               $scope.taskCol.push( $scope.newTask);
               $scope.newTask = {};
          }
});
```

This is my controller. I have a mongo collections named Tasks. The form is meant to submit the data which is the saved to the task collection. the form is not submitting and i get no errors on my console so i'm not really sure what the issue is.

```
   .state('tab.newtask', {
        url: '/newtask',
        views: {
            'tab-tasks': {
                templateUrl: 'client/templates/new-task.ng.html'
            }
        },
        controller:"taskController"
    })
```

This is the code defining the template for that state and also the controller for the view

Comment: Try to add a `console.log` in your `$scope.addTask` function and come back to us if you see that it is showing message on console.

Comment: I added the console.log, but i get no message. Its as if the button isn't firing any event at all

Comment: Yes, you're right: the `$scope.addTask` is not called. Please, also check that your current controller is the one that handles the **New Task** view. You can simply put a `console.log` after `function ($scope, $meteor) {` for this.

Comment: i am sure i made the controller for the view. please check the edit in the question for that code

Comment: It looks ok to me. It depends on the context (the parent view). Be sure to have a `<ion-nav-view name="tab-tasks"></ion-nav-view>` in your files.